# Multiple joins with multiple on statements using Linq Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

This is a sample SQL query which I wanted to convert to Linq Lambda expression.

```
Select u.unitName
from dbo.cmp c
inner join dbo.unit u on c.UnitProducerId = u.unitid
inner join dbo.unit u1 on c.unitid = u1.unitid
inner join dbo.catalogpart cp on u.unitid = cp.unitid and c.producer = cp.producercode
where u.unitid = 'A8311A16-3C3B-47B4-8184-7A9E336081F1'
group by u.unitName
```

I wanted to convert the above SQL into Linq Lambda expression as follows.

```
context.cmp
.Join(context.Units, cmp => cmp.UnitProducerId, u => u.UnitId, (cmp, u) => new { cmp, u })
.Join(context.Units, m1 => m1.cmp.unitId, u1 => u1.UnitId, (m1, u1) => new { m1, u1 })
.Join(context.CatalogParts, m2 => m2.m1.u.unitId, cp => cp.UnitId, (m2, cp) => new { m2, cp })
.select(new {
    supplier = m2.m1.u.UnitName
    }
.groupby(g => g.UnitName)
.selectMany(s=> s);
```

When I run this Lambda expression, it didn't give me the correct results (Compared with the results of SQL query). I was unable to add two on statements in single join line.

```
inner join dbo.catalogpart cp on u.unitid = cp.unitid and c.producer = cp.producercode
```

How can I get me Lambda expression corrected? Appreciate your help.

Comment: `Join(context.CatalogParts, m2 => m2.m1.u.unitId, cp => cp.UnitId, (m2, cp) => new { m2, cp })` => `Join(context.CatalogParts, m2 => new { unitid = m2.m1.u.unitId, producer=???} ,cp => new {unitid=cp.UnitId, producer=???}, (m2, cp) => new { m2, cp })`

Comment: @Robert McKee - Thank you very much for your answer. As per your suggestion, I will correct the particular line as follows.           


Join(context.CatalogParts, m2 => m2.m1.u.unitId, cp => cp.UnitId, (m2, cp) => new { m2, cp }) => Join(context.CatalogParts, m2 => new { unitid = m2.m1.u.unitId, producer=m2.m1.cmp.producer} ,cp => new {unitid=cp.UnitId, producer=cp.producerCode}, (m2, cp) => new { m2, cp })